# No solution here works for my "Class 'PDO' not found."

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, cpanel, voyager

I know there are questions with similar titles here but none seem to work for me hence the reason to create a new question.

So here's the problem, i have a site that works perfectly on localhost where i am sure has PDO support but after uploading on my shared hosting i get the

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class 'PDO' not found

the solutions here all involve editing php.ini and installing PDO however, i am on a shared hosting without access to php.ini file or ssh.

I am using laravel 5.5, php version 7.2 with a voyager backend.

here's what my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

[image]
Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You can't install PHP extensions on most shared hosting accounts but PDO should be standard for all providers.  Ask your provider why it isn't enabled.

Comment: @ggdx Shared Host... No access to... So I would bet that Farm there is no access to sudo either

Comment: @devon I just contacted them and they say PDO is enabled.

Comment: @Umar745, it'd be pretty easy to prove that wrong by putting up a phpinfo()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact your Hosting support and let them enable PDO for you.

In some hosting you can overwrite php.ini by creating php.ini file in your hosting root. These are the extensions you need to enable in php.ini if you are in windows hosting.

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Edit:

Check if PDO is already installed by your hosting provider.
Create index.php file or any other file which you can access. The content must have

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If PDO is installed already, the next thing to do is running composer install (SSH access required). You must delete your vendor folder beforehand. Assuming that your public folder is /var/www/html. go to the html directory and run

```
composer install
```

Comment: I just contacted them and they said PDO is enabled.

Comment: Most hosting can't be trusted (atleast to my experience), just create a file which you can access. like index.php and print out the php info. E.g: <?php phpinfo() ?> in the index.php file and see search for pdo.

Comment: you're very right. it turns out PDO was not activated, but it is now and everything is working well.

Comment: @Umar745 happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's late but i here is my solution. i was facing the same problem in Laravel 5.6 and i didn't have SSH access for some reason. but when i change my `PHP version` from `7.2` to `7.1` it works for me.

Hope this will work with someone who doesn't have shell access.