# Class 'PDO' not found when uploading laravel website to cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

After uploading website to cpanel it shows error Class 'PDO' not found. The version of laravel is 5.8 and php is 7.1. Please help in solving this issue.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No solution here works for my "Class 'PDO' not found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797834/no-solution-here-works-for-my-class-pdo-not-found)

Comment: What hosting company you are trying on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this error because PDO extension is not enabled in your PHP configuration. If this is shared hosting server, you will have to contact your hosting provider to enable it for your account. If you own your server, please ensure that you have enabled PDO extension. You can check it using simple phpinfo page.

Depending on your server's configuration steps may be different to enable PDO extension. If it is cPanel server, it can be enabled using EasyApache 4.